# Concurrent requests to PHP using FastCGI on IIS

Tags: php, iis, cgi, fastcgi

Some of my PHP script might run for a long time, 10 seconds or so. I noticed that other requests have to wait until the previous request is processed. That makes the site unresponsive for a while.

Is there any setting in FastCGI to fix that problem or should I switch to something else, such as CGI?